# Remember the latest opened UIView controller

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an app that has three UIViews, when I open the app it opens automatically the first UIView. I want to make swift remembers the UIView and when the app will re-open it should start on this UIview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Seyhun said, use userDefaults like this:
make a global variable, for example `lastSelecteUIView: Int = 0`, in controls that changes UIView, change this variable such so when you read it you will be able to understand which UIView was the last (like 1 is first view, 2 is second view etc.)

```
var save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
save.setInteger(lastSelecteUIView, forKey: "lastView")
save.synchronize()
```

This code can be also placed in control's which change UIVIew actions.

In viewDidLoad you loading save value using

```
lastSelecteUIView=save.integerForKey("lastView")
```

Then you check `lastSelecteUIView` value and change UIView depended on variable value

Comment: Thank you! I I'll try it at home tonight :)

Answer (score 1):

It'is not actually Swift question, it's about design. If I understand your question correctly, you can practically use `NSUserDefaults` to store which `UIView` you want to open next time app launches. On `viewDidLoad` check which `UIView` referenced on `NSUserDefaults` render it first.

Comment: Thanks for information but how to use NSUserDeafults to store the UIView?