# Save datePicker value using NSUserdefaults(xcode,swift2)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, datepicker

How can we save the value of datepicker through nsuserdeafaults or anything.For example if a person chooses 5 pm then when he return to app he should see 5pm on the datepicker.I do not know how to include nsusersdefault into this below is the code

```
@IBAction func NotificationButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
    cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID("NotificationID")

    //dateformatter for alert
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)

    var notifications:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notifications.fireDate = datePicker.date
    notifications.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notifications.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    notifications.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
    notifications.userInfo = ["UUID": "NotificationID"]
    notifications.alertBody = "Quote of the day"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notifications)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
var datePicker = /* Get Your Date Picker from somewhere */

// Store value using User Defaults
let currentDate = datePicker.date
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentDate, forKey: "Current-Date")

// Retrieve Value using User Defaults
if let date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Current-Date") as? NSDate {
    datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: If i am using IBAction so should i include this into that ? @Davidsilverfarmer

Comment: If the IBAction is send by a Date Picker then you could use the above to store the value (the part under Store value using user default). Then whenever you need the date you can use it to set the date pickers date (the part under retrieve value using user defaults)... Where exactly you'd put this depends on your application...

Comment: thanks man it worked and one thing my notifications are coming late by 30 seconds i dont know why @Davidsilverfarmer

Comment: Your welcome. What I would think of right know is that when you're experiencing delays in your UI make sure you're only using the main thread to access UIKit classes...

Comment: if it is not accessing on main thread what code should i write ? @Davidsilverfarmer

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date object to string.

Then store it in user defaults.

And again to use it, you can again convert it from string to date.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about using UserDefault [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896322/remember-the-latest-opened-uiview-controller/31897209#31897209)
Except "`setInteger`" and "`integerForKey`" you can use `setValue` and `valueForKey` with adding `as! String`, for example

It would be like

```
someVariable = save.valueForKey(forKey: "title") as! String
```

Comment: the designated commands of `NSUserDefaults` are `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:` and there is a convenience method `stringForKey:` to get a `String`. The methods `setValue:ForKey:` and `valueForKey:` are key value coding methods which have a different behavior.